# Hide all columns in range except for cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that I need to hide columns except for the one column that I choose in cell B2. The range of cells is D through infinity. So, when I enter 5 in cell B2 it will hide columns 1-4 and 6 through 1000 or something. See row 2 has the column numbers. Column "i" Row "2" has a 6, this is the name of the column I want to show only when I enter value into B2.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDQbs.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your vba code (I am assuming the macro assigned to that button `Reset`), you can use:

```
Range(Columns(4), Columns(8)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range(Columns(10), Columns(16384)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

Instead of numbers 8 and 10 you can use `Cells(2,"B")+2` and `Cells(2,"B").Value+4`.

```
Range(Columns(4), Columns(Cells(2,"B")+2)).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Range(Columns(4), Columns(Cells(2,"B")+2)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range(Columns(Cells(2,"B")+4), Columns(16384)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

I have added the first line so whenever you change the value in range `B2`, the whole columns are shown again and repeats the process for the new column number.